# How to parse below xml in oracle sql

Tags: sql, xml, database, oracle

```
<root>
<transactiondata>
<Info>
    <![CDATA[1234ABCD]]>
<Details>   
    <Data Name="Names">
        <FirstName>A</FirstName>
        <LastName>B</LastName>
        <DisplayName null="true"/>
    </Data>
    <Data Name="Names">
        <FirstName>C</FirstName>
        <LastName>D</LastName>
        <MiddleName>MName</MiddleName>
        <DisplayName>D C</DisplayName>
    </Data>
    <Data Name="Address">
        <Country>ABCDEF</Country>
    </Data>
</Details>
</Info>
<Info>
    <![CDATA[345JUHDE]]>
<Details>
    <Data Name="Names">
        <FirstName>AB</FirstName>
        <LastName>BC</LastName>
        <DisplayName>BC</DisplayName>
    </Data>
    <Data Name="Names">
        <FirstName>CD</FirstName>
        <LastName>DF</LastName>
        <MiddleName null="true"/>
    </Data>
    <Data Name="Phone">
        <PhoneNumber>7654333</PhoneNumber>
    </Data>
</Details>
</Info>
</transactiondata>
```

The above xml was stored as clob in ClobData table,I want to parse this xml data as temporary table to join this temporary table with other different tables.

```
    CDATA   FirstName   LastName    DisplayName     MiddleName
1234ABCD    A           B           No Value        null
1234ABCD    C           D           D C             MName
345JUHDE    AB          BC          null            No Value
```

Can some one please guide me how to parse clob into above format.
I tried `TABLE(xmlsequence(extract(xmltype(clobdata.data_cache), '//Info/Data[@Name="Names"]'))) tempTable` but i am not able to access cdata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the XMLTable function](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions269.htm):

> XMLTable maps the result of an XQuery evaluation into relational rows and columns. You can query the result returned by the function as a virtual relational table using SQL.

In this case as you have multiple name nodes under each details section, you can either use two levels of XMLTable; the first gets the CDATA text and the details, the second expands the details to get the name information:

```
select x1.cdata, x2.firstname, x2.middlename, x2.lastname, x2.displayname
from clobdata c
cross join xmltable (
  '/root/transactiondata/Info'
  passing xmltype(c.data_cache)
  columns cdata varchar2(10) path './text()',
    details xmltype path 'Details'
) x1
cross join xmltable (
  'Details/Data[@Name="Names"]'
  passing x1.details
  columns firstname varchar2(10) path 'FirstName',
    middlename varchar2(10) path 'MiddleName',
    lastname varchar2(10) path 'LastName',
    displayname varchar2(10) path 'DisplayName'
) x2;

CDATA      FIRSTNAME  MIDDLENAME LASTNAME   DISPLAYNAM
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
1234ABCD   A                     B                    
1234ABCD   C          MName      D          D C       
345JUHDE   AB                    BC         BC        
345JUHDE   CD                    DF
```

or go straight to the names and then backtrack to the CDATA:

```
select x.cdata, x.firstname, x.middlename, x.lastname, x.displayname
from clobdata c
cross join xmltable (
  '/root/transactiondata/Info/Details/Data[@Name="Names"]'
  passing xmltype(c.data_cache)
  columns cdata varchar2(10) path './../../text()',
    firstname varchar2(10) path 'FirstName',
    middlename varchar2(10) path 'MiddleName',
    lastname varchar2(10) path 'LastName',
    displayname varchar2(10) path 'DisplayName'
) x;

CDATA      FIRSTNAME  MIDDLENAME LASTNAME   DISPLAYNAM
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
1234ABCD   A                     B                    
1234ABCD   C          MName      D          D C       
345JUHDE   AB                    BC         BC        
345JUHDE   CD                    DF
```

Change the sizes of the `columns` arguments to match the actual lengths of the names you expect to see.

You can then join `x` (or if you prefer `x1` and/or `x2`) - give the XMLTable's more meaningful aliases though! - to other tables as needed.

[Read more about using XQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/xdb_xquery.htm#ADXDB1700).

Comment: Thanks Alex,One more thing how to achieve ColumnValue as "No Value"  if it is like null="true" because i have few more columns which might not come in xml so,in that case value will be null eg; fullname varchar2(10) path 'FullName'

Comment: Alex i found the solution thank you so much. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36050202/check-length-of-column-in-xmltable